# Office Javascript API: MS Project identify parent task id and sub task id

Tags: office-js, office-addins, ms-project

I am working on building MS Project Web Add-in. Using the below function as a base with other functions I am able to retrieve the `task, id and resource name`.

```
// Get the maximum task index, and then get the task GUIDs.
async getTasks(guids: string[]): Promise<any[]> {
    return await Promise.all(
        guids.map(async guid => await this.getTask(guid))
    );
}

async getTaskGuids(maxIndex: number): Promise<string[]> {
    const guids = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
        guids.push(await this.getTaskGuid(i));
    }
    return guids;
}
```

Please see the below screenshot with indentation / sub tasks.

[image]

Now I need to identify if the task is sub task or indented task. What is the best way to identify this. Any sample code is really helpful. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getTaskFieldAsync` method to get specific field values for a task. For example this returns the [Outline Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.outlinelevel) of a task (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.):

```
_projDoc.getTaskFieldAsync(taskGuid, Office.ProjectTaskFields.OutlineLevel,
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            text.value = text.value + "Outline Level: "
                + asyncResult.value.fieldValue + "\n";
        }
        else {
            logMethodError("getTaskFieldAsync", asyncResult.error.name,
                           asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Also see the task [Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.summary) property to determine if a task is a summary or not. The [OutlineChildren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.outlinechildren) collection might also be useful as well as the [OutlineParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.outlineparent) property.

For reference, see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/project/create-your-first-task-pane-add-in-for-project-by-using-a-text-editor) on creating a Project add-in using JavaScript.

Comment: I must say you saved my hell a lot of time!! Thank you !!