# Office Javascript API: MS Project find the guid of modified task

Tags: office-js, office-addins, ms-project

This is in relation with my previous question [Office Javascript API: MS Project identify parent task id and sub task id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469675/office-javascript-api-ms-project-identify-parent-task-id-and-sub-task-id)

I am constructing a JSON payload  which will iterate through all tasks in MS Project and make a post call to the web app which we have as a `tasks`.

is there any way to identify in **MS Project** which Task has **modified**. It can be of any `ProjectTaskFields` change.  If so then I can run my below guid function to get that particular `task` and make a **PUT** request.

```
// Get the maximum task index, and then get the task GUIDs.
async getTasks(guids: string[]): Promise<any[]> {
    return await Promise.all(
        guids.map(async guid => await this.getTask(guid))
    );
}

async getTaskGuids(maxIndex: number): Promise<string[]> {
    const guids = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
        guids.push(await this.getTaskGuid(i));
    }
    return guids;
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You can use an event handler running in the desktop environment that can track task-level changes. See these posts: [stackoverflow.com/...microsoft-project-vsto-c-sharp-event-listener-when-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671970/microsoft-project-vsto-c-sharp-event-listener-when-changed) and [stackoverflow.com/...how-do-i-listen-for-a-project-change-event-from-an-ms-project-vsto-add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686672/how-do-i-listen-for-a-project-change-event-from-an-ms-project-vsto-add-in). Then flag the changed task by using a date field to record a timestamp.